# Creating a SQL insert statement with both parameters and select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to come up with a DB2 SQL statement that does the following, but I am not sure
if this is allowed.

I know that it's possible to `insert into tableA ( ... ) Values (?,?,?,...)`
and then assign values to those parameters `?`.

Is it possible to pre-defined the value of one of the parameter?

For example, one of the column that I am trying to insert is the `ID column` and I would like to make it something like `select max(id) + 1 from tableA`.

This is what I am trying to get to - is this syntax possible in `db2`?

```
insert into tableA (ID, Text1, Text2) VALUES (select max(id)+1 from tableA, ?, ?)
```

Anyways - any help would be appreciated!

thanks!!

Comment: I am curious why you'd not want to use autogenerated primary keys? `CREATE TABLE mytable (id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ...)`

Comment: I didn't have control on how the table was created, but thanks for the pointer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should works :

```
 insert into tableA values((select max(id)+1 from tableA),'text1','text')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting a primary key as an index on your table.

```
db2 alter table tableA add primary key (id)
```

This will create a column in your table which will auto-increment when you add a new record.
Source ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401melnyk/ )

Comment: Yes - this is one way to go about it to answer my question - but one the other hand is there a way to mix/match values and params?

Comment: In DB2, INSERT can take a VALUES argument OR a SELECT, but not both in one query:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafymultrow.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the `OVERRIDING USER VALUE` parameter:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
OVERRIDING USER VALUE 
SELECT 0,Text1, Text2
From TableB
```